# How to print an array /object in magento

Tags: php, magento

On Magento I have tried

```
   Mage::log ($order);
```

I suppose to get the array printed on my

```
   var/log/system.log
```

But instead the website does not load again, after few min it comes as timed out.

Comment: You are doing it right. The problem is that and order object is huge because of the references to other objects and is not a good idea to print it. Print only the data you need.

Comment: I am not sure what data are available in the array unless I print it. Could you please give me an example..

Comment: Try printing this: `Mage::log(array_keys($order->getData()))`. This should print you a simple array with keys of the order model instance. Then pick your key and just log this `Mage::log($order->getData($key))`.

Comment: Have you tried to use debugger?

Comment: I'm new to Magento, How do I use debugger ?

Comment: Mage::log(array_keys($order->getData())); it printed all the array key thanks ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following print the entire array in to MyArray.log

```
   Mage::log("Query product: ".print_r($order->debug(), true),null,'MyArray.log');
```

MyArray.log can be found in

```
   var/log/MyArray.log
```

The following Prints the array Keys

```
   Mage::log(array_keys($order->getData()));
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
Mage::log($order->toArray());
```

Comment: Mage::log(print_r($order, true));

Comment: Tried Mage::log($order->toArray()); and Mage::log(print_r($order, true)); Non worked .. . :(

Answer (score 1):

Try that: `Zend_Debug::dump($your_variable);`

And this is one of the best posts about that in my opinion: [MAGENTO DEBUGGING HINTS](http://www.atwix.com/magento/debugging-hints/)